# Issue when adding cart items to cart List in provider

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, provider, flutter-provider

I'm using provider to add items to my cart, but when I add items to the cart and print the cart List,
it appears as the following

[image: it appears as the following]

Here is my function

```
class CartList extends ChangeNotifier {
  Map<String, CartModel> _cart = {};

  Map get cart => _cart;

void addToCart({required String productId,price,title,image}){
    // When a item is added to the cart that already exists, update quantity by one
    if(_cart.containsKey(productId)){
      _cart.update(productId,(value)=> CartModel(key: value.key,name:value.name,image:value.image,price:value.price,quantity: value.quantity! + 1,totalPrice: 0));
    } 
    // If the item is not in the cart, add it
    else {
      _cart[productId] = CartModel(key: productId,name:title,image:image,price:price,quantity: 1,totalPrice: 0);
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if that structure is right but I just want to print each property inside my cartPage.

here is my **cartPage.dart**:

```
class cartPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final shoppingList = Provider.of<CartList>(context);
    final items = shoppingList.cart;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Cart"),
      
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
        children: [
          ListView.builder(
            itemCount: items.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              final item = items[index];
              return ListTile(
                
                title: Text(item.name),
                subtitle: Text('${item.quantity}'),
                
                // trailing: IconButton(
                //   icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                //   onPressed: () => shoppingList.removeItem(index),
                // ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answered , It's correct to see this value when printing your cart.
However, you can still map through your values using ListView.builder.

Answer (score 0):

in your `CartModel` class you have to add an ovverride of `toString` so that when you print that class, it prints you whatever value you put in the `toString` method:

```
   class CartModel {
    
    final String aRandomProperty;
    
    @override
      String toString() {
        return 'aRandomProperty: ${aRandomProperty}';
      }
```

now when you try to print it, it will work